# Create zip of folder with same name by command line

Tags: command-line, zip

I'm creating a folder where any file or folder that comes in gets `zip`ped, encrypted with a password and moved to another folder, but I want to keep the original name of the folder that came in instead of a generic name. Here is my command:

```
 zip -P asdf -r ~/Desktop/output2/genericname.zip  ~/Desktop/input2
```

How could I do it?

Comment: So how resulting zip file is to be named ? input2.zip ?please provide an example

Comment: Sorry if I was no clear enough. So I have to folders input2 and output2. I want to use the input2 as a inbox where any file or folder that came in has to be zip and secure or encrypt with a password (that is already on the script) but I want to keep the original name of the incoming folder or file. example: an folder with the name Book is drop in input2 has to be zip and send to output2 as Book.zip... I'm using Run Apple script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `input2` is the name of the file you want to zip, and not the directory that contains the things you want to zip, you could use this `for` loop

```
for i in $HOME/Desktop/*; do echo zip -P asdf -r $HOME/Desktop/output2/$(basename "$i").zip  "$i"; done
```

`echo` is just for testing. If the output looks right, remove `echo` and run the command again.

As a script

```
for i in $HOME/Desktop/*; do 
   echo zip -P asdf -r $HOME/Desktop/output2/$(basename "$i").zip  "$i"
done
```